# How can I make a modal message box with AngularJS?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have this code:

```
<body>
    <div>
      xxx
    </div>
    <div id="error"
         ng-show="er.msg">
        <div style="color: white; background-color: purple; height: 2rem; display: flex; align-items: center;">
            <div style="width: 90%; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;">{{ er.msg  }} </div>
        </div>
    </div>   
    <div>
      xxx
    </div>  
</body>
```

Is there a way that I can make a mask appear over the whole page to prevent user input while the error dialog is showing? Note this is angular so I can make a div show with ng-show="er.msg" or I can hide a div with ng-show="!er.msg".

Comment: Hii i think this link helps you.. 
https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog

Comment: Why not use [ui-bootstrap modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [bootstrap modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) implementation, you can easily achieve that yourself.

You will mainly need 3 css classes

//To cover the whole page with transparent window, clicking this should close the modal window.

```
.modal-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1040;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

//Actual modal window above transparent window with higher z-index

```
.modal {
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1050;
}
```

// This is to attach to body tag to remove scroll bar, to prevent double scroll bar. when dialog is closed this class should be removed.

```
.modal-open {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```